# Delete loaded file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepond

While using the `files` option to load pre-uploaded files from the server, Then the `revert` doesn't send the DELETE request.

```js
files = 
[
    {
        source:21240,
        options:{
            type:"local",
            file:{
                name:"Hello - Copy.pdf",
                size:"30742",
                type:"application/pdf"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        source:21242,
        options:{
            type:"local",
            file:{
                name:"Hello.pdf",
                size:"30742",
                type:"application/pdf"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was totally wrong! I set file type local so it wasn't working. I set it to `limbo` now it sends `DELETE` request using the `revert` method.

```js
files = 
[
    {
        source:21240,
        options:{
            type:"limbo",
            file:{
                name:"Hello - Copy.pdf",
                size:"30742",
                type:"application/pdf"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        source:21242,
        options:{
            type:"limbo",
            file:{
                name:"Hello.pdf",
                size:"30742",
                type:"application/pdf"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks to this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-filepond-revert-remove-o2yqo?file=/src/index.js:670-674) created by Ric.